# Getting keyvaluepair values dynamically

Tags: c#

Basic question here, but I'm new to c#.  I have code that basically says: if condition A, then execute a code block on property X.  If condition B, then execute the same code block on property Y, and so on.  Instead of having to duplicate my code blocks just to change one single property name -  a.Value.ValueX to a.Value.ValueY - is there a way to call ValueX or ValueY as variables, such as a.Value.{$propertyName} ?

```
public static class Conditions
{
    public static bool A { get; set; }
    public static bool B { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjects
{
    public int ValueX { get; set; }
    public int ValueY { get; set; }
}

public class MyCollection
{
    public Dictionary<int, MyObjects> listOfObjects = new Dictionary<int, MyObjects>();

    public static void DoConditions()
    {
        foreach( var a in listOfObjects)
        {
            if(Conditions.A)
            {
                // do code using value x
                if (a.Value.ValueX > 0)
                    continue;
            }
            else if(Conditions.B)
            {
                // do the exact same code using value Y
                if (a.Value.ValueY > 0)
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just extract the common code to a method which you call with `a.Value.ValueX` and `a.Value.ValueY`?

Comment: No because the code that is duplicating execution is looping through the 2nd level of a nested dictionary that would make it not useful.  I would end up still duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by this. Making your example representative of the real issue would help here.

Comment: are ValueX, ValueY… all of the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int val = 0;
if(Conditions.A)
    val = a.Value.ValueX;
else if(Conditions.B)
    val = a.Value.ValueY;

// Your code block here using "val".
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable and populate it with the appropriate property value:

```
foreach( var a in listOfObjects)
{
    int value;
    if(Conditions.A)
        value = a.Value.ValueX;
    else
        value = a.Value.ValueY;

    if(value > 0)
        continue;
    //other code using `value`
}
```